# How do I add additional versions of mysql to homebrew cellar

Tags: mysql, sql, homebrew

I used homebrew to install mysql and it installed 5.6.15. I need to have some version of 5.5 installed. Currently in usr/local/Cellar I have just 5.6.15, how can I add an older version to that so I can use the 'brew switch' command to use the version I want to?

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://gotofritz.net/blog/geekery/install-specific-version-homebrew/) details how to install older versions of a formula, using Subversion as an example. In a nutshell, to get MySQL 5.5:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/versions
$ brew -S mysql
automysqlbackup                mysql-cluster              mysql-proxy
groonga-normalizer-mysql       mysql-connector-c          mysqlreport
mysql                          mysql-connector-c++
mysql++                        mysql-connector-odbc
josegonzalez/php/php53-mysqlnd_ms   homebrew/versions/mysql51
josegonzalez/php/php54-mysqlnd_ms   homebrew/versions/mysql55
josegonzalez/php/php55-mysqlnd_ms
$ brew install mysql55
```

Comment: Maybe `brew link mysql55 --force` is needed too.